# Family Link: how to set daily limits for a child regardless of which devices he/she uses

Tags: android, google-family-link, chromebook

I can't find a way to set a daily limit to my daughter regardless of her devices. I want her to spend 2h max on screen no matter which device she uses on that day.

Yet she's getting 2h on her tablet and 2h on her smartphone.

Am I missing something? Does Family Link only allow to set device-specific limits?

Comment: @Rubén: There's also a Google Family Link web application.  [(Source.)](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/41482/how-to-manage-your-childs-google-family-link-settings-using-a-web-browser#41483)  Therefore, I wonder if you could please reopen this question?

Comment: @tealhillsupportsMonica This question isn't about using Google Familiy Link web app, it's about using the mobile app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment one can not set the maximum screen time limits no matter which device the child uses.

As mentioned on the [official Google help site](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7103340):

> **Daily limits apply to each Android device or Chromebook your child uses**. For example, if you set a daily limit of 2 hours, your child would get 2 hours of time on each device.

### As an alternative

**If and when** the limit is reached on a specific device you could **give your child bonus time** without changing their daily limit or bedtime schedule.

> 1. Open the Family Link app Family Link.
> 2. Select your child.
> 3. On the card for one of your child's Android or Chromebook devices, the Bonus time Bonus time chip will appear when your child’s device is
>    locking soon or if your child’s device has already locked.
> 4. Tap Bonus time Bonus time.
> 5. Follow the instructions on the screen to give your child bonus time for the day.

Comment: Thank you. Is it me or this limitation makes literally no sense? Which parent want to apply limitations on a per-device basis instead of on a per-child basis??

Comment: Google decisions :/

Comment: @drake035. I agree with you. Normally I only come across such stupid concepts at Apple. It's surprising to find this with google. Disappointing.