# Family link and multiple devices

Tags: google-family-link

My son has 2 devices. Tablet and phone. I gave a limit to 1 hour. And I realized that the limit is assigned to both devices. So in the end he has 2 hours.
How can I assign the limit as a sum for all devices?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/141268/117311) yet?

Comment: No I didn't. But this answers it. Thanks.

Comment: You could always upvote it :)